# Field data changed is not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I am trying to check if the value changed in a Laravel model, `isDirty` never executes. If I remove `isDirty` Data Updating is working fine, only `ìsDirty` is not working.

```php
public function update(TeacherRequest $request, $id)
{
    $teacher = Teacher::find($id);

    if ($teacher->isDirty($request)) {
        $new_data = $teacher->$request;
        $old_data = $teacher->getOriginal($request);
        return response()->json([
            'msg' => $new_data,
            'msg' => $old_data
        ]);
    }

    if ($teacher->save()) {
        $teacher->update($request->all();
    }
}
```

I tried to check only `one column` as well if it was changed.

**One Column check:**

```php
if ($teacher->isDirty('efirst')) {
    $new_data = $teacher->efirst;
    $old_data = $teacher->getOriginal('efirst');
    return response()->json([
        'msg' => $new_data,
        'msg' => $old_data
    ]);
}
```

`efirst` is the name of the first column and input field.

I am getting nothing as output even if I change data.

Comment: From what I gathered, `isDirty()` checks if the model has changed since you fetched it. You call `isDirty()` right after fetching the model, without any changes being made, so no changes have been made yet, thus the check returns false and the code in the `if` block doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.  Model's `isDirty()` will return true if the fields have been modified on the model itself. It expects one optional parameter, which is the list of *parameters to check*, not their new values. If you check `isDirty()` right after `Model::find()`, it will always return *false*.
So you need to do it the other way around:

1. Find the model
2. Set the new fields from the request to it (don't save!)
3. Check `isDirty()`

Comment: like this?   if($teacher->save()){
                    if ($teacher->isDirty('efirst')) {
                      return response()->json([
                        'dirty' =>"dirtyyyyyyy",

                      ]);
                    }

Comment: No, you need to check isDirty() before save(). When you save, it becomes "clean" again.

Comment: i added if condition above save and it's ignoring dirty condition.

Comment: You need to assign the values from the $request to the $teacher first. $teacher-> efirst = $request->efirst, etc.

Comment: i am doing mass assignment, i need to $request again? with mass assignment?

Comment: I don't see mass assignment in your code. Make sure you do the assignment after you find the model and before you check isDirty(). Also make sure you set the  "fillable" property on the model, otherwise mass assignment will have no effect: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thank you, got it, i saved data in variable in start then i called dirty before save method.